# How to position this few divs inside div

Tags: html, css

I got a problem with center horizontally dives. I got a menubar and inside it a few dives . Menubar is centered on the page but these dives inside sticks to left side, i tried padding but then menubar is getting bigger. I put code below and maybe someone will know how to do it

```
.menubar1{
   background: #ffffff00;
   width:95%;
   max-width:95%;
   margin-right: auto;
   height: 70px;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-top: 5%;
   border-top-right-radius: 50px;
   border-top-left-radius: 50px;
   position: static;
   margin-bottom: -18px;    
}
.menubar1>div{
   width: 17%; 
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: top;
   height: 45%;
   zoom: 1;
   background-position: center;
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 23px;
   padding-top: 10px;
   font-family: cursive;        
   font-weight: 600;
   margin-top: 5px;
}
.menubar1:after {
   content: "";
   width: 100%;
   display: inline-block;
}

.how2{
   background-color: #white;
   background-size: cover;
   max-width: 250px;
   min-width: 135px;
   color: gold;
 }

////HTML CODE
<div class="menubar1">
    <div class="how2" style="cursor: pointer;" 
     onclick="window.location='http://somepage.com';">Title</div>
     ...and other 4 same divs
</div>
```

Comment: `and other 4 same divs` : why not adding them ...

Comment: So much wrong here, just the three worst straight from the HTML code: `div`, `style="cursor: pointer;"`, `onclick="window.location...` - why go through so much trouble to make stuff _work/ look like_ a list of links, instead of _using a list of links_ ...? ul/li/a is what you want to use here. You should go read up on the basics/ current "state of the art" of creating navigation menus.

Comment: this css code is from one file and rest of html code is from another file .less. The code I wrote is simplified only to show a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean center like this?

```
text-align:center;
```

on menubar1. Also inline styling is poor practice, and redundant.

```css
.menubar1{
   background: #ffffff00;
   width:95%;
   max-width:95%;
   margin-right: auto;
   height: 70px;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-top: 5%;
   border-top-right-radius: 50px;
   border-top-left-radius: 50px;
   position: static;
   margin-bottom: -18px;   text-align:center; 
}
.menubar1>div{
   width: 17%; 
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: top;
   height: 45%;
   zoom: 1;
   background-position: center;
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 23px;
   padding-top: 10px;
   font-family: cursive;        
   font-weight: 600;
   margin-top: 5px;
}
.menubar1:after {
   content: "";
   width: 100%;
   display: inline-block;
}

.how2{
   background-color: #white;
   background-size: cover;
   max-width: 250px;
   min-width: 135px;
   color: gold;
 }
```

```html
<div class="menubar1">
    <div class="how2" style="cursor: pointer;" 
     onclick="window.location='http://somepage.com';">Title</div>
     <div class="how2" style="cursor: pointer;" 
     onclick="window.location='http://somepage.com';">Title</div>
     <div class="how2" style="cursor: pointer;" 
     onclick="window.location='http://somepage.com';">Title</div>
     <div class="how2" style="cursor: pointer;" 
     onclick="window.location='http://somepage.com';">Title</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I highly suggest learning more about css flexbox. It is browser friendly and will make creating fluid layouts much easier for you in the future.

In the example I provided, the `flex` property is applied to the parent container that container the divs that need to be centered. `Justify-content:center` horizontally centers them and `align-items:center` aligns them vertically. There are many different options to control your layout and you can learn more about them here:https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
.parent{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  width:100%;
}

.child{
  flex: 0 0 20%;
  margin:.5em;
  background-color:black;
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2</div>
  <div class="child">3</div>
  <div class="child">4</div>
</div><!--parent -->
```

Comment: text-align:center; helped but I saw your link it's very interesting, and I really need to learn about flexbox. Thanks for Your answer ! :)

Comment: It has completely changed my workflow over the last year and I haven't used `float` ever since, lol. I'm pumping out websites much faster now.

Happy coding!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to center a div, you can use margin: 0 auto;

example:

```
divToCenter{
      margin: 0 auto;
}
```

More information [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp)

Comment: note op wants multiple divs centered in a parent div. This only works if one div is being centered.

Answer (score 0):

First don't use position css property on your css file:

you have to give position value default. Then you have to change the code like this

```
<style>
 .menubar1{
  background: #ffffff00;
  width:50%;
  max-width:95%;   
  height: 70px;  
  margin:0 auto;
  }
 .menubar1>div{
  width: 10%; 
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 45%;
  zoom: 1;
  background-position: center;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 23px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  font-family: cursive;        
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-top: 5px;
 }
.menubar1:after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
 }

.how2{
  background-color: #white;
  background-size: cover;
  max-width: 250px;
  min-width: 135px;
  color: gold;
}
</style>

<div class="menubar1">
    <div class="how2" style="cursor: pointer;" 
    onclick="window.location='http://somepage.com';">Title</div>
    <div class="how2" style="cursor: pointer;" 
    onclick="window.location='http://somepage.com';">Title</div>
    <div class="how2" style="cursor: pointer;" 
    onclick="window.location='http://somepage.com';">Title</div>
    <div class="how2" style="cursor: pointer;" 
    onclick="window.location='http://somepage.com';">Title</div>
```

here i changed your code. Hope I think you expect like this. My Output is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I felt like your code could of been more efficient, Maybe i'm not seeing the big picture but the code below works a lot better:

```css
  body {margin:0;}

  .maxScreenSize {margin: 0 auto;max-width: 1280px} /* you dont usually want your menu expanding for ever, this puts a limit on how far the menu will extend, change 1280px to which ever screen size you think will for best for this element */
  
  .topnav-containter {
    background-color: #777; /* This is grey for testing, you can change it back to white if you like*/
    border-top-right-radius: 50px;
    border-top-left-radius: 50px;
    padding-left: 50px; /* Added so that hover effect doesn't appear on the curves */
    padding-right: 50px; /* Added so that hover effect doesn't appear on the curves */
    margin-top: 10px; /* I dropped the %5 because I think fruther along in your web build (maybe the responsiveness stage) the percentage here wont make sense. */
  }
  
  .topnav {
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 23px;
    font-family: cursive;        
    font-weight: 600;

  }

  .topnav a {
    float: left;
    width: 20%; /* 5 buttons, so 100 / 5 = 20 */
    color: gold;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 16px 0; /* Padding for top and bottom only, left and right will cause the buttons to not fit evenly across */
  }
  
  /* Drop this if you dont want a hover effect */
  .topnav a:hover {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: black;
  }
```

```html
  <div class="maxScreenSize">
    <div class="topnav-containter">
      <div class="topnav">
        <a href="#">Title</a>
        <a href="#">Title</a>
        <a href="#">Title</a>
        <a href="#">Title</a>
        <a href="#">Title</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```